# Magento - Mage_Core_Model_Abstract load() purpose of $field parameter

Tags: magento

What is the purpose of the second parameter to `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` `load()`

i.e. the $field parameter.

I have looked in the the method and in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` at its load method which also gets `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` `load()` calls.

Its just not clear to me what is happening.

Can someone explain this

Answer (score 6):

If provided, the column with the same name as the $field param will be the filter (where). If not, the resource model will use the primary key column which is set in the resource model definition.